# Error when implementing a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to write a method for requesting user input via dialog box multiple times which only stops requesting when an empty string is entered.

Each entry needs to be added to a list, which I'll call `aList`. I'm using a bespoke import for the dialog box in my program which you may not be familiar with called `Dialog.request("");`.

I dont necessarily have to use this but I do need a pop up dialog box which only closes when an empty string is entered or cancel is pressed. Hopefully you can help

```
public void addToList()

{
    String inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    aList.add(inputName);
}
```

With the while loop it is as follows

```
public void addToList()
{   String inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    while(inputName !=""){
    aList.add(inputName);
}
}
```

I tried to implement a while loop but that lead to the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at unknown line
```

Any tips are appreciated. So far invoking the method with `x.addToList();` only adds one entry at a time. When I put in the while loop or do-while loop I get the error

Comment: From the Error, it seems very likely that you have created an infinite loop. Make sure the loop terminates. Also, you should always make sure to include all relevant code in your question, in this case the loop that produces the Error

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. Should I be using a while loop or a do-while loop?

Comment: If you know (and can guarantee) there will always be at least one operation, a `do-while` is appropriate

Comment: @JackB please post full while loop code...

Comment: I have added it in my edit.

Comment: First, compare `String`s with the `equals()` method. Secondly, you are checking if the `inputName` is not empty, if so add it to your list. And then the story repeats. In other words, that while loop will always be `true` given that `inputName` does not hold a reference to the empty `String`.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify: I need to make a new `String` variable and assign an empty string to it? The while loops checks that the `inputName` is equal to it before adding it to the list?

Comment: @Jyr means do the follow: `if (!"".equals(inputName))`.  `.equals` in the place of `!=`.  Strings are objects so using `!=` will compare the address of the object, not the value of the object.  In the case of immutable classes like Strings, you won't see a difference... but good practice.

Comment: I think its just a design skin for the standard `input.request` pop up box for use with BlueJ which is what I'm having to use. Feel free to write you answers as if this were the case. Like I said I could always just be using `input.request` but this way is neater. If needs be I could simply change to that

Comment: @xbakesx Ah ok I'll test that out

Comment: @brso05 I deleted my comment so it didn't confuse anyone.  But I will point out that Strings are a little magic.  `"hello world" == "hello world"` evaluates to true where as `"hello world" = new String("hello world")` evaluates to false... Java does try to reuse object references of Strings when you use the implicit constructor.  So you very correctly pointed out that the immutability has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @xbakesx google java interning strings...http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-intern-example/    String literals "hello world" are automatically interned by java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems here.  First off when comparing `Strings`/Objects you should use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` not `!=` or `==`.  The next problem is you aren't re-prompting a user for input inside your loop.  You might want something like this:

```
public void addToList()
{
    String inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    while(!inputName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        aList.add(inputName);
        inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    }
}
```

If the user enters a name you should keep asking them for another name until they don't enter a name.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
while(inputName !=""){
    aList.add(inputName);
}
```

There are 2 issues with this. First you cannot compare strings with `!=` or `==`, as this will instead compare the *references*. User `String.equals()` instead.

Second, you are checking against a variable that **does not change**. This is critical because it means that the condition in the loop will either *always* or *never* be true. You must change the condition at some point within the loop or else it will never terminate.

The easiest way you can do this is by simply requesting user input within the loop like so:

```
String inputName = "nothing";
while(!inputName.equals("")){
    inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    aList.add(inputName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an equal - but in my opinion more elegant - alternative to previous answers, the loop could be expressed with a do-while statement:

```
String inputName;
do {
    inputName = Dialog.request("Please Enter A Name");
    if (!inputName.equals("")) {
        aList.add(inputName);
    }
} while (!inputName.equals(""));
```

Comment: I'll check that that works as well for future reference, thanks for your input

Comment: yeah that works great as well, I would upvote you if I weren't but a lowly SO noob

Comment: I just gave your question an upvote. Your noobness should decrease a bit :-)